# What is diff between upgraded SharePoint 2013 and newly installed SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, upgrade

I just want to know, is there any difference between SharePoint 2013 which is upgraded from SharePoint 2010 and newly installed SharePoint 2013.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Both are a new installation but the main difference between the New installation and upgrade process is the data migration from old SharePoint 2010 farm to the new SharePoint 2013 farm in the upgrade process.

You should also be aware of There is not `in place upgrade method` (upgrade 2010 to 2013 on the same farm) , only the `database-attach method` is the supported process.

So the upgrade process will require a new SharePoint 2013 farm installation plus **data migration** include the content databases, service applications databases from Sharepoint 2010 farm to the new SharePoint 2013 Farm.

Below are the steps of SharePoint 2013 upgrade process , you should note that the first step is Create a SharePoint 2013 farm that applied through performing a new installation

[image]

For more details check [Overview of the upgrade process to SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

Basic difference is the data.if you bring data from previous version of sharepoint then it will be called upgraded farm.

When some say, his farm is upgraded that's mean

- he installed and configure the new sharepoint 2013 farm
- he migrated data from previous version of sharepoint I.e. 2010 or 2007
- for migration he may used database attach method or 3rd party tool

But for a fresh installed farm means.

- he installed Sharepoint 2013 farm and configure it
- now he is creating new site collections and other stuff
- no data from previous version.